# Laravel custom or extended belongsToMany

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I have a table 'users' and a table 'groups'.
In the application, i am working on, the administrator can assign groups to users.
So there is a many-to-many relationship between these tables.

With the following code i defined this relation:

```
public function groups()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Group');
}
```

This way i can retrieve the groups this user is assigned to:

```
$users = User::with('groups')->get()
```

But above this, settings in the application provide the posibility to set a group for all the users.
Is it possible to define a relation so that i retrieve all groups that are related to the user plus the one that is assigned to all users according to the setting? Something like this:

```
public function groupsInclDefaultGroup()
{
    $defaultGroupId = Setting::getSetting('defaultGroupId');
    return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Group')->..??..($defaultGroupId);
}
```

.

```
$users = User::with('groupsInclDefaultGroup')->get();
```

Comment: did you try `...->orWhere('group_id', $defaultGroupId)` on that relationship ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but: Yes i tried; it made things worse; now the result contains no groups at all.